# pandas: convert one matrix to another

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a matrix (df) so I get another (df2), and don't have a clue as to how..

```
[df]
      X     Y     Z
a  None     x  None
b  None  None     x
c     x  None  None

[df2]
    X     Y     Z
 None     a  None
 None  None     b
    c  None  None
```

if it helps, here's a construction of df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, 'x', None], [None, None, 'x'], ['x', None, None]],
     index=['a', 'b', 'c'],
     columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
print(f'\n{df.to_string()}')
```

Comment: Based on the excellent answers below, I also discovered the following `df.where(df!='x', df.index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.notnull(), df.index)

print(df)
      X     Y     Z
a  None     a  None
b  None  None     b
c     c  None  None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `mul`

```
df.eq('x').mul(df.index.tolist(),0)
Out[109]: 
   X  Y  Z
a     a   
b        b
c  c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `apply`:

```
ddf = df.apply(lambda row : pd.Series(row.name if el == 'x' else el for el in row), axis=1)
ddf.columns = df.columns
```

Last line because column names are lost, so you need to reassing them.
Is basically replacing all `'x'` with the row indexes, leaving other values as they are (even if they are not `None`).

Result `ddf` is:

```
      X     Y     Z
a  None     a  None
b  None  None     b
c     c  None  None
```